# Why setText in android gives error when only int is passed in it?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, android-studio

Following is my code

```
 public void display(int number){
        TextView quantity = findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        quantity.setText(number);
    }
```

When I give `setText(number)` then it gives error which states that no resource found.
But when I give `setText("" + number);`
then it works perfectly. 
Am I missing some fundamentals?

Comment: Ok thank u i got it!!

Comment: Why is this being voted to reopen? The linked duplicate is perfectly appropriate, and the top answer there explains the issue exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
public void display(int number){
    TextView quantity = findViewById(R.id.quantity);
    quantity.setText(String.valueOf(number));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setText()` only accepts `String` value and `int number` is a number so we have convert it to `string`.